# How to set BottomSheetDialogFragment to be the same color as the system navigation bar for Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to make my BottomSheetDialogFragment and the bottom navigation color be the same color. Setting the color for navigation bar is working well as i set it to white but the color of the buttons remains to be white as you can see in the picture. This is what i have in the styles:

```
<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/AppModalStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/white</item>

        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppModalStyle" parent="Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ic_dialog_background</item>
        <item name="behavior_peekHeight">300dp</item>
    </style>

theme.xml
    <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarSize">0dp</item>
        <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/AppBottomSheetDialogTheme</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/screen_background_color</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    </style>
```

ActivityMain:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            val nightModeFlags: Int = resources.configuration.uiMode and
                    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK
            when (nightModeFlags) {
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {
                }
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {
                    val decorView = window.decorView
                    decorView.systemUiVisibility = FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS or
                            SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_NAVIGATION_BAR or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR
                }
                Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_UNDEFINED -> {
                }
            }
        }

        window?.navigationBarColor = resources.getColor(com.imediavan.common.R.color.screen_background_color)
        window?.statusBarColor = resources.getColor(com.imediavan.common.R.color.screen_background_color)
```

The property **android:windowLightStatusBar** is working well on the Activity but for the dialog its not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to build bottom sheet dialog with rounded corners and after showing bottom sheet this problem happen round your bottom sheet like this.

1 - build style in theme.xml like this

```
<style name="CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog" parent="">
        <item name="cornerFamily">rounded</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopRight">16dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeTopLeft">16dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomRight">0dp</item>
        <item name="cornerSizeBottomLeft">0dp</item>
    </style>
```

2 - build another style in theme.xml like this

```
<style name="CustomBottomSheet" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomSheet">
        <item name="shapeAppearanceOverlay">@style/CustomShapeAppearanceBottomSheetDialog</item>
    </style>
```

3 - build another style as like as this one

```
  <style name="CustomBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.BottomSheetDialog">
        <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/CustomBottomSheet</item>
    </style>
```

4 - as final step add this line to your base application theme in theme.xml

```
 <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/CustomBottomSheetDialog</item>
```

100% worked for me :))))))

Comment: I tried it and it seems it does not work